# Two computers sharing LAN each has one computer and both are connected via wifi

Tags: networking

All machines are running Ubuntu 16.04

My setup is like so:

[image: Computer Setup]

- Computer B has HostAPD acting as a WAP
- Computer A is connected to B via LAN
- Computer C is connected to computer B as a client via WIFI
- Computer D is connected to C via LAN

I am trying to get a setup that allows me to communicate fully end to end (A to D) but my I am not quite sure how my setup should look?

I tried using routing tables by pointing my gw to the machines that share their LAN lines but I cant seem to reach across the wifi to the other machines.

Comment: Are the computers B and C close to each other or far away from each other? Would it be possible for them to share a router or access point?

Comment: they are right next to each other but theyre expected to be far as well

Comment: It is easy, if you use a common router, but if the computers will be far away, and you need to communicate via the internet, you must spend some time to make sure that your system is protected from attacks via the internet. In both cases I think it is a good idea to make at least one computer an SSH server by installing `openssh-server`.